# How to findout CPU hardware series number from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: cpu, embedded-linux, broadcom

I am trying to find out datasheet for a broadcom cpu chip, I can get the below cpuinfo dump, but how do I findout exact chip series number?

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type             : 968380GERG
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS4350 V8.0
BogoMIPS                : 598.01
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

processor               : 1
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS4350 V8.0
BogoMIPS                : 606.20
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

Answer (score 0):

BMIPS 4350 identifies a series of Broadcom chips such as the BCM93384WVG and BCM63168. But in this case, the syste type suggests a BCM968380.

Comment: tried that in google, no datasheet returned to me, is this confidential?